# Huawei appgallery api does not return comment list of an app

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery

I try get comments list from app_id. I do everything as in the documentation, but I do not understand why I cannot get the list of comments.

```
import requests
import json
import datetime,time
from datetime import timedelta,datetime

client_id = "5****";
client_secret = "95C92DF16****";
grant_type = "client_credentials";
r = requests.post('https://connect-api-drru.cloud.huawei.com/api/oauth2/v1/token', 
    json={"grant_type": grant_type, "client_id":client_id, "client_secret":client_secret})
js = json.loads(r.text)
token = js["access_token"]

begin_time = (datetime.strptime('2010-02-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')- datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
end_time =  (datetime.strptime('2021-02-19 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')- datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()

app_id =  "103154181"

url = "https://connect-api-drru.cloud.huawei.com/api/reviews/v1/manage/dev/reviews/"
countries = 'RU'

headers = {'Authorization':  'Bearer ' + token, 'client_id':client_id}

r = requests.get(url + "?appId=" + app_id + "&beginTime=" +str(int(begin_time)) + "&endTime=" +str(int(end_time)) + "&countries=" + countries+ "&page=1", headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Request output

```
{"ret":{"rtnCode":0,"rtnDesc":"success"},"data":{"reviewList":[],"hasNext":0,"total":0}}
```

[Screen from admin menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2SBi.png)

p.s. **Documentation**
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-getreviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following code's time is wrong.

```
begin_time = (datetime.strptime('2010-02-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')- datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
end_time =  (datetime.strptime('2021-02-19 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')- datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
```

You're counting the number of **seconds** from January 1, 1970 to the present,which according to  to the [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-getreviews),The value is the total number of **milliseconds** since 1970-01-01 08:00:00.

[image]

Comment: begin_time = datetime.strptime('2021-02-01 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timestamp() * 1000
end_time = datetime.strptime('2021-02-19 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timestamp() * 1000
pls add correct answer